# Creating a document in Domino Data Service(REST api)

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus, interop-domino

I am trying to create a document in Reservation form using Domino Data Service(REST api), response is showing document is created but when i am trying to access that reservation(xyz's) using Notes client it is not showing up.

URL : http://server/Conf.nsf/api/data/documents?form=Reservation
Payload: {
    "@authors":
    ["server",""
    ],
    "@form":"Reservation",
    "From":"xyz",
    "AltFrom":"xyz",
    "Chair":"xyz",
    "AltChair":"xyz",
    "Principal":"xyz",
    "SequenceNum":1,
    "ORGState":"5",
    "ResourceType":"1",
    "ResourceName":"BELLA VISTA/Building15",
    "Room":"BELLA VISTA/Building15",
    "Capacity":2,
    "_ViewIcon":133,
    "AppointmentType":"3",
    "StartTimeZone":"Z=-3005$DO=0$ZN=India",
    "EndTimeZone":"Z=-3005$DO=0$ZN=India",
    "Topic":"Test Meeting",
    "SendTo":"CN=BELLA VISTA/O=Building15",
    "Encrypt":"0",
    "Categories":"",
    "RouteServers":"server",
    "StartDate":"2015-03-28T06:30:00Z",
    "StartTime":"2015-03-28T07:30:00Z",
    "StartDateTime":"2015-03-28T06:30:00Z",
    "EndDate":"2015-03-28T07:30:00Z",
    "EndTime":"2015-03-28T07:30:00Z",
    "EndDateTime":"2015-03-28T07:30:00Z",
    "UpdateSeq":1,
    "Author":"xyz",
    "ResourceOwner":"",
    "ReservedFor":"xyz",
    "ReservedBy":"xyz",
    "RQStatus":"A",
    "Purpose":"Test from REST",
    "NoticeType":"A",
    "Step":3,
    "Site":"Building15",
    "ReserveDate":"2015-03-28T06:30:00Z"
}

Answer (score 1):

If you're successfully creating the document but unable to see it, that suggests that you have a problem with a Reader Names or Author Names field that is denying you access to the document.

Do you have Manager access to the conf.nsf database, and Full Access Administrator rights on the server?  If so, activate your full access rights via Domino Administrator, before opening conf.nsf and see if you can find your document, then check the document properties and examine all fields with SUMMARY READ-ACCESS NAMES or SUMMARY READ/WRITE-ACCESS NAMES types to determine what you've put there. Compare to manually created documents to see what should be there.

(If you lack the necessary permissions for this, either work with an administrator who has the rights, or set up a test server as AFAIK, there's no way to test the Domino Data Service with a local replica.)

Comment: I am able to see my booking after opening Conf.nsf,but while opening that booking it is giving me error "Field:'dStartTime':Incorrect datatype for operator or @Function:Time/Date Expected"

Comment: Then you should update your question with that informaiton. For debugging: look at the Reservation form in Domino Designer, find the formula for the field dStartTime and check the fields it is dependent on. Something is not set correctly and/or has the wrong data type.

Comment: Resource Owner and Author are the two fields with SUMMARY READ-ACCESS NAMES or SUMMARY READ/WRITE-ACCESS NAMES types when i create from Notes Client but it is SUMMARY only when i do it through REST Service.

Comment: I don't know if the strongtype json option provides for the ability to set those field types properly -- I don't see that in the documentation; but the computewithform=true option should take care of it. However, this does seem to be unrelated to any of the problem now that you've stated that you can in fact see the documents.

Comment: Note that the answer posted to your question over on the IBM site (http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ndseforum.nsf/xpTopicThread.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=076B3F57B6CD5B4485257E12003EB9AD#B8F873E7E550AA8B85257E12006AF7DB) does suggest that the strongtype option will likely be helpful for the Time/Date Expected issue.